# mySQL Query to grab multiple time frames

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently using 4 queries to grab a count of occurrences over 4 different timeframes.

```
SELECT count(*) WHERE keyword='keyword' AND time>A AND time<B;
SELECT count(*) WHERE keyword='keyword' AND type>B AND time<C;
SELECT count(*) WHERE keyword='keyword' AND type>C AND time<D;
SELECT count(*) WHERE keyword='keyword' AND type>D AND time<E;
```

I figure there has to be a way to merge these into a single query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to combine the queries

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN time > A AND time < B THEN 'A-B'
         WHEN time > B AND time < C THEN 'B-C'
         WHEN time > C AND time < D THEN 'C-D'
         WHEN time > D AND time < E THEN 'D-E'
       END,
       Count(*)
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  keyword = 'keyword'
       AND time > A
       AND time < E
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN time > A AND time < B THEN 'A-B'
            WHEN time > B AND time < C THEN 'B-C'
            WHEN time > C AND time < D THEN 'C-D'
            WHEN time > D AND time < E THEN 'D-E'
          END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `union` :

```
SELECT  'AB',  count(*) WHERE keyword='keyword' AND time>A AND time<B;
UNION
SELECT  'BC', count(*) WHERE keyword='keyword' AND type>B AND time<C;
UNION
SELECT  'CD', count(*) WHERE keyword='keyword' AND type>C AND time<D;
UNION
SELECT  'DE', count(*) WHERE keyword='keyword' AND type>D AND time<E;
```